# function inside template no work but when set logic inside template work?

Tags: angular

I have logic which work good -> example:

This is work good. When I want to set my values inside ts and switch logic in ts.file component:

and inside ts component:

**No work.**

WHy ?

I am also try with:

No work

What is problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `isPagination` method returns the exact opposite of what you expect. There's no need for the ternary operator part (`condition1 && condition2 ? true : false`) - the statement will be coerced into a boolean anyway.

This is the correct function:

```
public isPagination() { 
  return this.pagination && this.pagination?.totalPages >= 1;
}
```

Comment: does not work as expected. There is a problem somewhere.